# Vue js how render curly brackets variables with in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

in my data object

```
items: [
        { name: "Breakfast", comp: "breakfastItems" },
        { name: "Lunch", comp: "lunchItems" },
        { name: "Dinner", comp: "dinnerItems" },
        { name: "Dessert", comp: "desertItems" }
      ]
```

where *comp* is a computed property.
in my component template I want to achive something like this using a for loop.

```
<span v-for="n in items">
{{n.comp}}
</span>
```

this doesn't work because I need to add {{}} when it's rendering. How do I do that?

Comment: you need shomething like that? `{{ '{' + n.comp + '}' }}`

Answer (score 1):

To bind computed properties inside your template via dynamic interpolation, you can use the [`$root`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root) variable.

Assuming that the `comp` properties you've listed are collections underneath, the template might look like:

```
<span v-for="n in items">
    <span v-for="m in $root[n.comp]">{{ m }}</span>
</span>
```

[Here's a demonstration of the suggestion.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8WsMvU?p=preview)

Comment: This would only work if the computed properties were all in the root element.